# Print Chinese Characters on a printer using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to print Chinese to a printer using PHP's
printer module (php_printer.dll). I've printed Chinese successfully from
Notepad, so I know the printer can print Chinese.

I send the bytes to the printer using
printer_draw_text(). The printer just intreprets the
bytes as ascii characters, and prints out a string of
those weird characters. I've used
mb_convert_encoding() to convert the string to UTF-8
format before sending it to printer, but the result is
just another string of weird ascii characters.

So, where is the problem? How do I force the printer
to interpret the bytes in another encoding? Or ...
should I convert the bytes into another encoding, such
as UTF-7, UTF-16, etc???????

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do

1. Set document type or header as `content="text/html;charset=utf-8"`
2. Save those user Chinese characters in database with field collation as `utf8_unicode_ci`

Use below code in html.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>`